# Aggregating dataframe to give sum of elements and string of grouped indices

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use groupby to give me the sum or mean of a number of elements, and a string of the original row indices for each group. So for instance, the dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,3,4],[2,3,4],[2,5,6],[7,8,3],[11,12,13],[11,2,3]],index = ['p','q','r','s','t','u','v'],columns =['a','b','c'])

    a   b   c
p   1   2   3
q   1   3   4
r   2   3   4
s   2   5   6
t   7   8   3
u  11  12  13
v  11   2   3
```

I would then like df to be grouped by 'a', to give:

```
     b    c    indices
1    5    7    p,q
2    8    10   r,s
7    8    3    t
11   14   16   u,v
```

So far, I've tried:

```
df.groupby('a').agg({'score' : np.sum, 'indices' : lambda x: ",".join(list(x.index.values))})
```

But am receiving an error based on 'indices' not existing, can anyone advise how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way aggregation works is that you give a key and a value, where the key is a **pre existing** column name and the value is a function to map on the column.

So to get the sums the way you want, you do the following:

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby('a')
>>> grouped.agg({'b' : np.sum, 'c' : np.sum}).head()
     c   b
a         
1    7   5
2   10   8
7    3   8
11  16  14
```

But you want to know the rows that have been combined in a third column. So you actually need to add this column before you `groupby`! Here is the full code:

```
df['indices'] = range(len(df))
grouped = df.groupby('a')
final = grouped.agg({'b' : np.sum, 'c' : np.sum, 'indices': lambda x: ",".join(list(x.index.values))})
```

then you get the following result:

```
>>> final.head()
   indices   c   b
a                 
1      p,q   7   5
2      r,s  10   8
7        t   3   8
11     u,v  16  14
```

if you have any further questions, feel free to comment.